# Textbox value change on runtime exception

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am changing value of `Textbox` on runtime, but when user clears the `Textbox` using backspace i got exception of invalid string.

```
private void txtTradePrice_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtRate.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txtTradePrice.Text) * 12).ToString();
}

private void txtRate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtTradePrice.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txtRate.Text) / 12).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Because an empty string cannot be converted to an integer.  Look at using Int.TryParse() instead.

Comment: Google for generalized error text.

Comment: You are getting invalid string because you cannot convert empty string to int. 
Moreover, as far as I remember, setting `.Text` field on property will fire `TextChanged` event, so you'll get circular firing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code must check if the string is empty. When user clears the text, it becomes empty and Convert to int will throw exception and it cannot convert blank to a integer value.

```
private void txtTradePrice_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTradePrice.Text))
   {        
     int number;
     if(Int32.TryParse(txtTradePrice.Text, out number))          
       txtRate.Text = (number * 12).ToString();
   }
}

private void txtRate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRate.Text))    
   {
      int number;          
      if(Int32.TryParse(txtRate.Text, out number))          
         txtTradePrice.Text = (number / 12).ToString();
   }
}
```

You should always use Int.TryParse.

Answer (score 0):

You should use int.TryParse, as it handles string problems.

```
private void txtTradePrice_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int tradePrice = 0;
    if(int.TryParse(txtTradePrice.Text, out tradePrice))
        txtRate.Text = (tradePrice * 12).ToString();
}

private void txtRate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rate = 0;
    if(int.TryParse(txtRate.Text, out rate))
        txtTradePrice.Text = (rate / 12).ToString();
}
```

Having this, nothing will be recalculated, when field is empty, or any other problem with text will occur (like invalid characters in input).